# When do I have to include moc*.cpp in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, moc

I understand the basic concept of why it is better to manually include `moc*.cpp` instead of leaving moc to do it itself, but I don't quite understand *when* I have to include it.

Let's say I have `mainwindow.cpp` and `mainwindow.hpp`, that require the moc to run on them. Here, I know I have to include `moc_mainwindow.cpp` in `mainwindow.cpp` (and not in `mainwindow.hpp`).

But what if I have `foo.cpp` that includes `mainwindow.hpp`, do I have to include `moc_mainwindow.hpp` in `foo.cpp`? It just isn't clear to me how this whole moc thing works, so can someone explain this? (and, yes, I did research this on the internet - I read the Qt Documentation about moc but it didn't make it clear to me).

Comment: In my own code I never manually include moc_*.cpp however I am using CMake instead of QMake or any other method.

Comment: It depends where you declare your QObject-s

Comment: @drescherjm I also use cmake, but according to the book Professional CMake: A Practical Guide, "If the number of classes processed by AUTOMOC in this way is very large, it can put pressure on compiler resources and even cause build failure in extreme cases." It says that the solution for this is to explicitly include moc_basename.cpp in basename.cpp.

Comment: I work with reasonably projects usually between 50K to 250K lines and several hundred source files. Although I am not going to say that I have had no issue with moc in the past. Although much of this was in the more distant past.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What do you mean by this? My Q_OBJECTs are declared inside the mainwindow.hpp header file.

Comment: @drescherjm So you mean it really isn't necessary to include moc_basename.cpp in files?

Comment: I have not needed to do that. Although I have seen other code not written by me use this.

Comment: Your explanation about `Q_OBJECT` should go into your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moc’ed file contains the implementation of the meta object, the signal-slot sugar and few other things. It means that if you compile it more than once you will have duplicated symbols on linking stage.

Actually your best option would be to not include the moc’ed file and add it as other normal compilation unit of your project. It simplifies your code, prevents linkage errors, and have a good impact in your compilation time when implementation files are modified.

Nevertheless, if you decide to include the moc’ed file manually you have to do it only in one place to prevent the aforementioned duplicated implementations.

Another case where a direct include is useful for expressiveness is when you declare a class with the `Q_OBJECT` in a .cpp file: including the moc’ed in the same file is coherent with the fact that such class belongs to only that file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've read it's preferred that I manually include moc_*.cpp manually. Now everyone is saying to me that it isn't really necessary. So what's your experience? It isn't required?

Comment: For example, having the moc’ed file as a separate compilation unit may help to reduce the compilation time when you only modify the implementation of the class. This is useful for classes with many slots/signals, and when you modify many implementation files.

Comment: In my experience, when most of your classes have the Q_OBJECT macro including moc_*.cpp manually may significantly reduce the full rebuild time. I did a small test on a project where 103 out of 154 header files contained the Q_OBJECT macro; adding `#include "moc_*.cpp"` to each cpp file improved build time by about 30%.